# Why can a double store so much more information than a long? (JAVA)

Tags: java, double, byte, long-integer

If a long and a double are both 8 bytes, why can a long store -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a double can store 1.7*10^308? It seems like something to the 308th power would take a lot more storage. (Sorry it's a short question)

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing up two things: information and representation. The information is the same  in both cases (8 bytes, or 64 bits), the difference is only in representation. You pay the expanded range of values with precision. At a certain size, you can add `1` to a `double`-value and it will not change the result. For more information on the different representations, look up [One's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) and [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that `double` only has 15-17 significant decimal digits of precision, while `long` has 18-19 digits of precision. As Turing85 said, `double` gives up digits of precision in return for storing an exponent, so that `Long.MAX_VALUE` (which is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, ending in 7, not 8) will be stored as `9.223372036854776e18`, which as you can see has lost the last 3 digits of precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A double can store exactly as many distinct values as a long because both have the same number of bits. The difference is how the bit patterns are interpreted. For a long this is very simple. If you add one to the bit pattern then the interpreted value changes by one (except for over/underflow). For a double this is more complicated. The bits are separated in multiple parts that represent a base and exponent value. This results in a behavior where the interpreted values of a double aren't distributed equally. You can for example represent very small differences between numbers if the number itself is small, but if the numbers are big, the small differences cannot be represented anymore. e.g. 0.0001 is different from 0.0002 but 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000.0001 is the same as 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000.0002.

You can easily test this behavior with the following code.

```java
double a = 0.0001;
double b = 0.0002;
double c = 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.0001;
double d = 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_000.0002;

System.out.println(a == b);
System.out.println(c == d);
```

This will print

```java
false
true
```

Comment: tysm for the clarification. I was thinking that for the same storage size, longs are obsolete.

Comment: It is crucial to understand these differences. Floating point numbers are always approximate. For a double you have something like 15 digits of precision, this means that if your number is longer than this number of digits, the lower value ones are dropped. For a float value this number is something around 7 or 8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little program that illustrates why double cannot always do long's job correctly. The function `test` prints its argument and the results of incrementing it by 1 in each of long and double:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public strictfp class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(100);
        test(1L << 60);
    }

    private static void test(long l) {
        double d = l;
        System.out.println("long "+l + " " + (l + 1) + " double " + new BigDecimal(d) + " " + new BigDecimal(d + 1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
long 100 101 double 100 101
long 1152921504606846976 1152921504606846977 double 1152921504606846976 1152921504606846976
```

With input 100 both are exact, because all integers in that region can be represented exactly in double as well as long.

With input 2<sup>60</sup> long still gets the exact answer, but double does not, because in that region some integers cannot be represented exactly in double. 2<sup>60</sup> can, 2<sup>60</sup>+1 cannot.